# zsh fail to keep unquoted `$*` and `$@` equal

Tags: shell, zsh, quoting

All shells tested do the same for the (quoted) pair "$*" and "$@" with this code:

```
c='set a b @ c; IFS=:,@ ; a=$(printf "<%s> " "$*"); b=$(printf "<%s> " "$@"); printf "%-20s and %-20s\n" "$a" "$b"'

d=(sh ash dash attsh ksh lksh mksh bash b44sh y2sh zsh zsh4 "zsh -y")
for shell in "${d[@]}"; do
    printf '%15s: ' "$shell"
    $shell -c "$c"
done
```

Results:

```
         sh: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
        ash: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
       dash: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
      attsh: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
        ksh: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
       lksh: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
       mksh: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
       bash: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
      b44sh: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
       y2sh: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
        zsh: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
       zsh4: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
     zsh -y: <a:b:@:c>            and <a> <b> <@> <c>
```

However, for the unquoted `$*` and `$@` the tests (only `$c` needs to change):

```
c='set a b @ c; IFS=:,@ ; a=$(printf "<%s> " $*); b=$(printf "<%s> " $@); printf "%-20s and %-20s\n" "$a" "$b"'
```

The result is:

```
         sh: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <> <> <c>   
        ash: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <> <> <c>   
       dash: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <> <> <c>   
      attsh: <a> <b> <> <c>       and <a> <b> <> <c>      
        ksh: <a> <b> <> <c>       and <a> <b> <> <c>      
       lksh: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <> <> <c>   
       mksh: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <> <> <c>   
       bash: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <> <> <c>   
      b44sh: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <> <> <c>   
       y2sh: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <> <> <c>   
        zsh: <a> <b> <@> <c>      and <a> <b> <@> <c>     
       zsh4: <a> <b> <@> <c>      and <a> <b> <@> <c>   
     zsh -y: <a> <b> <> <> <c>    and <a> <b> <@> <c>
```

Leaving aside the removal of repeated values in ksh, all shells act in the same way except for zsh. Which presents a `@`. This may be reasonable if the idea that variables are quoted by default (or no spliting is performed by default).

But in trying to get the default of all other shells and ask zsh to split (unquote) variables used, we get diferent values for `$*` and `$@`

Changing again `$c` to:

```
c='set a b @ c; IFS=:,@ ; a=$(printf "<%s> " $*); b=$(printf "<%s> " $@); [ "$a" = "$b" ] && echo "Yes" || echo "Nope"'
```

we get this clear results:

```
         sh: Yes
        ash: Yes
       dash: Yes
      attsh: Yes
        ksh: Yes
       lksh: Yes
       mksh: Yes
       bash: Yes
      b44sh: Yes
       y2sh: Yes
        zsh: Yes
       zsh4: Yes
     zsh -y: Nope
```

Only zsh fails to have unquoted (split) `$*` and `$@` equal.

Comment: Seems like your question boils down to _why does `zsh -o shwordsplit -c 'IFS=:; echo $@' sh x a:b` output `x a:b` and not `x a b`_. And I think the answer is: _you've found a bug_. You may want to report it on the zsh mailing list (maybe after checking on the latest development version)

Comment: Related: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=888

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the title of the question is correct and exactly describe your comment.

Comment: Issue reported by @StéphaneChazelas on [zsh-workers](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01537.html)

Comment: @Arkanosis Thanks for the info. Good idea to get it solved.

Answer (score 0):

That was a [bug](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01492.html) (regression) [introduce in version zsh-4.3.11-dev-4](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01494.html) in 2011 and now fixed by [this changeset](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/f7c3aa170b8c36b146ba7644cf3912cb1329a5d2).

The fix is now included in versions 5.3 (released on 2016-12-11) and newer. The bug affects versions 4.3.11-dev-4 to 5.2.